Finding Two Distinct Square Roots of I
I am working through the book Linear Algebra Done Right. I am stumped on this exercise question.
I used ChatGPT and understand up to here:

I just don't understand how I deduce that the real part=0 and the imaginary=1? Is this a fundamental concept I'm unaware of? Something else?

Do you understand what "Equate real and imaginary parts" means?

I just figured it out.
Since the statement is set to i, a^2-b^2 must be 0, while 2ab must be 1.

"Equate the two expressions", would have been clearer.

This is the first time I have seen ChatGPT successfully complete a proof or derivation with no errors. Well done to it, I guess...

What does the “I” in the title refer to? The identity matrix or $\sqrt{-1}$? Considering this is an exercise from a linear algebra textbook, it seems the former is correct interpretation, but the body of your question suggests otherwise. Please clarify.

Don't use ChatGPT for anything except personal amusement. It is not a search engine, it is not a valid reference. It is a synthetic text extruder that works by deciding what is the likely next word on the basis of what the previous words and prompt were. This is a classic example. You want two square roots of the identity linear transformation. It is giving you two complex square roots of the imaginary number $i$.

@ChristianE.Ramirez Except that it is extruding a proof to the wrong question. But what can you expect of a stochastic parrot?

@ArturoMagidin It never even occurred to me that OP might be referring to an identity transformation rather than $i$. If they are, that's on them for not being clear within this question, and the one they asked to ChatGPT (not that that would guarantee a coherent answer from ChatGPT). Might be a good idea for them to clarify in either case.

@ChristianE.Ramirez Well, the fact that the reference is "Linear Algebra Done Right", that the question is tagged linear-algebra, and that the question uses I rather than i was pretty sugestive. ChatGPT cannot produce "coherence". It produces synthetic text, and any coherence or meaning is projected onto it by the reader.

@ArturoMagidin The only such worded exercise in Linear Algebra Done Right is from chapter 1 at the end of section IA right after its subsection titled Digression on fields. Exercise 8 there (p. 10) reads: "Find two distinct square roots of $i$". So the imaginary unit is probably what is meant here, and the capital I in the title was accidental. The square root of an operator is first meantioned on p. 248, and defined on p. 251. There is no such exercise there: the phrase "two distict" occur a total of 7 times in the newest edition, and in only one of these is "square root" mentioned; on p.10

$a$ and $b$ are real. So the complex number $a^2-b^2+2abi$ can be expressed as a purely real component $a^2-b^2$ plus a purely imaginary component $2abi$.
Also, the complex number $i$ can be expressed as a purely real component $0$ plus a purely imaginary component $i$.
But these two complex numbers are equal. Therefore $a^2-b^2=0$ and $ab=\frac12$.
